# How to add custom scope-id for each rendering component in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Hi i have a situation like i want to download `css` files from different server whose css will have scoped attached to it, something like shown below.

[Downloaded css with scope id `data-v-98b365f2`]  - `component Dell`

```
.Dell[data-v-98b365f2]{
    ........
}
```

Append to head, the above css file

**now in my vue**

```
import Dell from './Dell.vue';
export default{
    name:'Main-Component',
    component:{Dell}, <-- here i want to attach above scope-id of downloaded css file i,e data-v-98b365f2
}
```

**Question:** how to render a component with given scope id in my case `data-v-98b365f2`

Note: my downloaded file scope-id will never change, even if changes i will get it.